# multiple integral where x,y,z are defined from R3 function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

It's an exercise i'm stuck with for some time.

We have integral

$$\iiint_D 4x^2 dx dy dz,$$ 
where $x,y,z$ belong to $D=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : (x^2/4) + (y^2/9) + (z^2/16) \le 1\}$.

I know how to solve the integral but i cant define $x,y,z$

Any help with **D** will be great.

**Adittion 9/8/2016 :**

I found a theorem saying that:

$$\iiint_D f\ dx dy dz = \int_a^b \int_h^h \int_g^g f(x,y,z) dzdydx $$

if D={**x**e[x0,x1] , **y**e[h0(x),h1(x) , **z**e[g0(x,y), g1{x,y) }

here is the link: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/gnagy/teaching/10-fall/mth234/w10-234-h.pdf **it is in page 1**

I tried this solution and found it extremely difficult to evaluate the integral to the end. Is the use of this theorem correct in this case? Is there an easiest way to solve this?

Comment: Please use MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D$ is an ellipsoid and you can easily compute your integral by a spherical change of coordinates: $x=2\rho \cos\vartheta_1$, $y=3\rho \sin\vartheta_1\cos\vartheta_2$, $z=4\rho\sin\vartheta_1\sin\vartheta_2$. In these variables 
$$
D=\{(\rho,\vartheta_1,\vartheta_2)\in\mathbb R^3\mid 0\leqslant\rho\leqslant 1\,,0\leqslant\vartheta_1\leqslant\pi\,,0\leqslant\vartheta_2\leqslant 2\pi\}$$ whereas the integral becomes

$$\int_D384\rho^4\cos^2\vartheta_1\sin\vartheta_1\, d\rho\, d\vartheta_1\,d\vartheta_2
=
384\cdot\int_0^1\rho^4\, d\rho\cdot\int_0^\pi \cos^2\vartheta_1\sin\vartheta_1\, d\vartheta_1\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}d\vartheta_2
$$

Now I let you conclude the computation!  The result (edited on sept 9) is $512\pi/5$.

Comment: Can you explain what you did there please? I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: My suggestion is about the change of variables in multiple integrals. You should learn about it in order to solve this kind of exercises.

Comment: I found a different solution to this without changing the coordinates. It's mostly based on algebra and it ends up like this: $$ \int

Comment: Using the theorem you cited is correct too, but somehow longer.

Comment: Thanks for the help @james. Can you please tell me what did you use to decide how to change the coordinates? Is it based on some algorithm/theorem or it's always the same for ellipsoids' ?

Comment: You are welcome! It's always like this for an ellipsoid.

Comment: I corrected a mistake in the computation of the jacobian!

Comment: So x is (sqrt of it's denominator) times the ρcosθ , y is (sqrt of it's denominator) times $$ρ*sinθ1*cosθ2$$ and the same for z? And one last question, how did you come up with $$ int_D 384ρ^4*cos^2θ1sinθ1 $$ ? I mean what steps did you follow. I tried to replace $$ 4x^2 with\ 4(2ρcosθ1)^2  $$ but didnt work.

Comment: There is the jacobian, as I wrote above!

Comment: The jacobian is equal to $2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot\rho^2\sin\vartheta_1$

Comment: Look at this please https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution